# Move the lines of the row adjacent (outside) to the pivot table when the Pivot gets updated

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, rows, auto-update

I am in a dilemma. I have financial information of actuals and budgets, "**Actuals**" are in a Pivot table because they are coming out of a database that gets updated each month but the "**Budget**" is hardcoded before the start of 2021, therefore when there is a new vendor, the pivot table will update automatically but the "**Budget**" rows will stay as it is.

Is there any way where the "**Budget**" rows can move in tandem with the updated pivot lines? I just need blank rows inserted in the "**Budget**" columns whenever there is a new vendor added. I have attached an image for reference [Actuals vs Budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGCzu.png)

This is my expected output [Expected output when a new vendor is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQTO6.png)

I am open to use VBA code for this as well.

Thank you

Comment: I think the best way is to keep the pivot table and the calculations separated. I would create a calculation sheet were I would put the actuals & budget and there I would have all the control.

Comment: But then in your calculation sheet, how would you update the new vendor details?

Comment: In the calculation sheet , you retrieve the information from the pivot table using GETPIVOTDATA. When the pivot table is refreshed the data in the calculation sheet will also be updated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I would have to use GETPIVOTDATA for each line and there more than 1000 such lines, it would take me a lot of time to add this formula

Comment: What is the source data of your pivot table?
You get the desired output from the Actual vs Budget?

Comment: Source is a huge data set (General Ledger) with more than 15 columns and around 7k rows that are filtered in the pivot by quarter, account, group and vendor name. Budget on the other hand is manually entered as per vendor name at the beginning of the year which means any new vendors added during the year will not have any budget allocated.

Comment: Bear with me! I am thinking that this might be a good and dynamic idea without the need to create macros in VBA.
1) Load your source data into PowerPivot. 
2) Create a table (object) with your budget data and add columns Group and Customer that will allow you to relate with your source data. Load this table into PowerPivot.
3) In PowerPivot create a relationship between the two tables
4) Create your a pivot  table from power pivot and this way you will get all the fields you need from both sources!
What do you think about this?